# Unexpected loading time for Tailwind css with Next.js in Server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, tailwind-css

For the website I'm creating I use next.js and for styling tailwind, but can't really see the benefit of server-side rendering that is expected from next.js, because the styles and images have a loading time when you open up the website, (assumingly related to tailwind) and with a slower connection it takes quite a few seconds to get to see the contents of the page.

How could I solve this loading issue and still stick to tailwind?

This is the website link, if you try it, you'll see the few seconds loading time before the content is visible:
https://www.revolin.io/

Comment: Got answers from nextjs and tailwind discussion:


https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32970


https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6862